# Openstack-Autopilot - adding HA on active cloud

Tags: openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I am currently running Openstack deployed with Autopilot on 3 Nodes, I see I need at least 6 Nodes to get HA configured, my question is:

Can I start using the cloud without HA on my 3 Nodes, then in due time add 3 more Nodes to enable HA for the cloud? Or would I have to completely reconfigure my cloud, loosing my Instances and other configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will have to redeploy with 6 nodes to get HA.

An HA deployment means that you can lose any machine and still be able to use your cloud (start new instances, access storage etc.). Instances on the machine that is lost will die.

Comment: Ok, what happens if one server fails on the HA setup? Or if you upgrade the hardware, and need to re-comission?